# How to use attr_encrypted with as_json and join and get the decrypted attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have an attribute encypted using [attr_encrypted](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted) and I'm using `as_json`. Under some circumstances I don't want the ssn to be part of a API response, and other times I want it to be included but using the name `ssn` not `encrypted_ssn` and to show the decrypted value. In all my cases `encrypted_ssn` should not be included in the result of `as_json`.

My first question is, how do I get `as_json` to return the decrypted `ssn` field?

With this code

```
class Person
  attr_encrypted :ssn, key: 'key whatever'
end
```

I want this

```
Person.first.as_json
=> {"id"=>1,
    "ssn"=>"333-22-4444"}
```

What I don't want is this:

```
Person.include_ssn.first.as_json
=> {"id"=>1,
    "encrypted_ssn"=>"mS+mwRIsMI5Y6AzAcNoOwQ==\n"}
```

My second question is, how do I make it so a controller using a model can choose to include the decrypted ssn in the JSON (`"ssn"=>"333-22-4444"`) or exclude the field (no `"encrypted_ssn"=>"mS+mwRIsMI5Y6AzAcNoOwQ==\n"`)? I don't even want encrypted values going out to the client if the controller doesn't explicitly specify to include it.

This is what I have so far and seems to work:

```
class Person
  attr_encrypted :ssn, key: 'key whatever'
  scope :without_ssn, -> { select( column_names - [ 'encrypted_ssn' ]) }
  default_scope { without_ssn }
end

Person.first.as_json
=> {"id"=>1}
```

I haven't figured out how to make this work in a way that includes the decrypted `ssn` field as in the first question. What I would like is something like this:

```
Person.include_ssn.first.as_json
=> {"id"=>1,
    "ssn"=>"333-22-4444"}
```

My final question is, how do I make the above work through a join and how do I specify to include or exclude the encrypted value (or scope) in the join?

With this code:

```
class Person
  has_many :companies
  attr_encrypted :ssn, key: 'key whatever'
  scope :without_ssn, -> { select( column_names - [ 'encrypted_ssn' ]) }
  default_scope { without_ssn }
end

class Company
  belongs_to :person
end
```

This seems to work like I want it

```
Company.where(... stuff ...).joins(:person).as_json(include: [ :person ])
=> {"id"=>1,
    "person"=>
     {"id"=>1}}
```

But I don't know how to implement `include_ssn` like below or alternatives to tell the person model to include the ssn decrypted.

```
Company.where(... stuff ...).joins(:person).include_ssn.as_json(include: [ :person ])
=> {"id"=>1,
    "person"=>
     {"id"=>1,
      "ssn"=>"333-22-4444"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this in a different way. Originally I was doing this:

`app/models/company.rb`

```
class Company
  # ...
  def self.special_get_people
    people = Company.where( ... ).joins(:person)

    # I was doing this in the Company model
    people.instance_eval do

      def as_json_with_ssn
        self.map do |d|
          d.as_json(except: [:encrypted_ssn] ).merge('ssn' => d.person.ssn)
        end
      end

      def as_json(*params)
        if params.empty?
          super(except: [:encrypted_ssn] ).map{ |p| p.merge('ssn' => nil) }
        else
          super(*params)
        end
      end

    end

    return people
  end
end
```

`app/controllers/person_controller.rb`

```
class PersonController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @people = Company.special_get_people

    # Then manually responding with JSON
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render nothing: true, status: :not_implemented }
      format.json do
        render json: @people.as_json and return unless can_view_ssn
        render json: @people.as_json_with_ssn
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However this was fragile and error prone. I've since refactored the above code to look more like this:

`app/models/company.rb`

```
class Company
  # ...
  def self.special_get_people
    Company.where( ... ).joins(:person)
  end
end
```

`app/controllers/person_controller.rb`

```
class PersonController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @people = Company.special_get_people
  end
end
```

`app/views/person/index.jbuilder`

```
json.people do
  json.array!(@people) do |person|
    json.extract! person, :id # ...
    json.ssn person.ssn if can_view_ssn
  end
end
```

And this ends up being a much better solution that's more flexible, more robust and easier to understand.